# Access 2013 Count

Tags: ms-access

I am working on a report in  Access 2013 I need to seperate the first 20 records in a column that contain a value and assign a name to them. Such as at 1-20 I need it to insert Lot 1 at 21-40 need to assign Lot 2 etc...  The report needs to be separated by lots of 20. I can also just insert a line when it reaches sets of 20 without a name if that makes it easier. Just need something to show a break at sets of 20.
Example: As you can see the report is separated by welder stencil. When the count in the VT column reaches 20 I need to enter a line or some type of divider to separate data. What our client is asking for is we separate the VT in sets of 20. I don't know whats the easiest way to accomplish this. I have researched it but haven't found anything.

[Example Report with Divisions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eg1vZ.jpg)

Comment: Since you are asking folks to help you, make it as easy as possible for them.  At least make sure images are rotated properly and of good quality.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Update the report's RecordSource query by adding "Lot" values for each row.**  There are multiple ways of doing this, but the easiest will be if your records already have a sequential, continuous numerical key.  If they do not have such a key, you can research generating such sequential numbers for your query, but it is beyond the scope of this question and no details about the actual data schema were supplied in the question.

   - Let's imagine that you have such a key column `[Seq]`.  You use the modulo (`mod`) and/or integer division operators (`\` - backslash) to determine values that are exactly divisible by 20, e.g. `([Seq] - 1) mod 20 == 0`.

     - Generate a lot value for each row.  An example SQL snippet: `SELECT ("Lot " & (([Seq] - 1) \ 20)) As LotNumber ...`
2. Utilize Access report **sorting and grouping** features --*grouping on the new Lot field*-- to print a line and/or label at the start of each group.  You can also have the report start a new page at the beginning or end of such a group.

   - The details about grouping can be found elsewhere in tutorials and Access documentation and are beyond the scope of this question.